# Using Physical EFI Disk Image as a Virtual Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, efi

I imaged an HP Envy laptop that has an M.2 Solid State drive. When I view the image file in FTK I can see 5 partitions including the Windows partition.

I would like a virtual instance of this physical machine and have tried two different ways, one with VMWare and the other with Virtual Box.

For VMWare, I mounted the image file as a physical drive, then created a Virtual Machine and selected to use the physical drive as the VMs hard drive. When it booted it said no operating system detected.

I then took the raw image and used VBoxManager convertfromraw command to turn it into a .vmdk file. Again when I boot it up in VirtualBox no operating system can be found again.

I believe it has to do with EFI, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for VirtualBox was to Enable UEFI boot on the mother board.

https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/enabling-uefi-on-virtual-machines.html